# how to disable delete in replication Cassandra datastax

Tags: cassandra, replication

my previous scenario i  used Sql server  one instance in amazon for live and the second
in local network for archiving by disable delete in replication can i do this in Cassandra or what best practices for this scenario?
 im using datastax  4.8.2

Answer (score 1):

You can disable delete,insert and update using the built-in Cassandra security

```
CREATE USER test_user WITH PASSWORD xxxx NOSUPERUSER;
GRANT SELECT TO test_user ON my_table;
```

Unfortunately, it will also disable INSERT and UPDATE. Right now there is no way to disable only DELETE.

Indeed, even if you disable DELETE and allow INSERT & UPDATE, it is still possible for the user to delete data, by just inserting `null` or updating with `null` values because inserting `null` == DELETE in **CQL** semantics